# Devise - recognize the last logged user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using a Rails 4 application with Devise support. Log in, register (etc) works perfectly.

I'm looking for a system for recognize last logger user **in the current browser**, to automatically fill the `username` field and display its avatar in the `login` page.

This can easily be done using a cookie (to store a `last_logged_user_id` or something else), but maybe this system is already present in Devise ?

Regards

Comment: Could you just find the last logged in user with `User.all.sort_by(&:last_sign_in_at)`. This sorts all users based on the last time they logged into the site. Then just take the first user of that relation.

Comment: @JustinLicata I don't want the last logged user of all my users. I want the last logged user for this current browser.

Comment: Agh, I misunderstood. Sorry.

Comment: Not foolproof, but could you do `User.where(last_sign_in_ip: request.remote_ip).order(last_sign_in_at: :desc).first` to get the last user that logged in from that IP address?

Comment: @Yule I'm not a fan of the method about `ip`, because it doesn't inplies user unicity (local network for example).

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm I agree, hence why didn't add as an answer, but may solve for some use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can piggy-back on devise's rememberable module. Most notably:

```
User.serialize_from_cookie(cookie_string)
```

[Source on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L37)

So pass the cookie into the method and it should return a user object based on that cookie. Note that you'll need rememberable enabled (if you don't want the 'remember me' tick box suggest you override devise's views and remove it) and then on login force the 'remember me' to be true.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I try to manipulate Rememberable module, and I think it's not dedicated to this. Indeed, the cookie is only used to re-authenticate user in the next 20 days when its session is closed. The main issue is that the cookie is deleted when user log out. I've done an override of several methods to keep this cookie alive, but when user is logged out, he is automatically logged in, and that's not what I want.